# putIfAbsent always returning null

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am working on a wordcount program, where I create `N` threads, and each thread receives a `char[]` buffer containing many different numbers like `[2355 3326 94438 123 123...]` I want to create a map where the key is the number itself, and the value is how many time it appears. I am converting from the `char[]` array to an integer as shown below.

However it seems that every time I call `putIfAbsent()`, it always returns `null`, meaning it did not find a key of that value. This does not make sense, as I have thousands of duplicate values in my text file. The map should end up being around 300kb, instead it is more than a gigabyte.

`newbyte[]` is a `char[]` containing ONLY numbers and spaces

**Why does putIfAbsent always return null?**

Also, when I print the map when finished, it looks like this:

```
233303192 = 1
1770057208 = 1
1323329638 = 1
1278321050 = 1
962422124 = 1
472527478 = 1
936125441 = 1
-350637153 = 1
-601349585 = 1
```

Which is quite odd, because the largest value of any input is 65535. Not sure how this makes any sense.

```
        public void run() {
            int counter = 0; int i; Integer check;  int j =0; int temp = 0; int intbuilder = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < newbyte.length; i++) {
                    if (newbyte[i] != ' ') { //delimiter is not found, so add to temp char array
                            intbuilder = (intbuilder * 10) + (int)newbyte[i];
                            counter++;
                    }
                    else {    
                            check = wordCountMap.putIfAbsent(intbuilder, 1);
                            if (check != null) { 
                                    wordCountMap.put(intbuilder, check + 1);
                            }
                            intbuilder = 0;
```

Comment: Perhaps not your problem but instead of `(int)newbyte[i]` you may mean `(int)(newbyte[i] - '0')`.

Comment: You are probably right, but it didn't help. By the way, my map is an ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the concurrent hash map. Its with the way you parse the character array

```
public void startThreads() throws InterruptedException{
        char[] input = {'1',' ','2',' ','3','4',' ','1',' ','2',' ','3','4',' ','1'};
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Worker(input));
        workerThread.start();
        workerThread.join();
        System.out.println("Count for 1 & 2 are "+countMap.get(1)+" and "+countMap.get(2));
    }

    private class Worker implements  Runnable{

        private char[] newbyte;

        public Worker(char[] newbyte){
            this.newbyte = newbyte;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()  {
            int number=0;
            for(int i=0;i< newbyte.length;i++){
                if(newbyte[i] != ' '){
                    number = (number*10)+Character.getNumericValue(newbyte[i]);
                }else{
                    Integer currentValue = countMap.putIfAbsent(number, 1);
                    if(currentValue != null){
                        countMap.put(number, currentValue+1);
                    }
                    number = 0;
                }
            }
            Integer currentValue = countMap.putIfAbsent(number, 1);
            if(currentValue != null){
                countMap.put(number, currentValue+1);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you declare `Integer currentValue` before the loop? Not sure if it is important, just wondering. I haven't tried this code out but I'll give it a shot. It looks like you are saying the key difference is here: `number = (number*10)+Character.getNumericValue(newbyte[i]);`

I am also a little confused as to the last three lines of code. It's outside the for loop. I'm guessing you accidentally wrote that code twice?

Comment: Ok so this code works on windows when running Eclipse, but when I try to run this java program via command line on a linux server, I get my crazy results again.

Comment: writing code after loop is not accidental .. if last character is not space then you will loose the last number .. try input without last character as ' '. are you executing the same program via command line on linux server or is it different with different inputs .. if you post logs it will help me answer

Comment: to your question declaring Integer outside loop is definitely .. but for small inputs GC should handle cleanup easily

Comment: I am executing the same program on a linux server.  The input is technically different, but it is the same format. All the input tokens are 4 -5 digit numbers like [2352, 12345, 20890...] The output on linux server is something like this:
`741926468 = 1
1290494101 = 1
703346691 = 1
-672872123 = 1
822927623 = 1
1479247979 = 1
90294613 = 1
` 

Obviously the numbers are not even from the input, and somehow there are negative numbers. Doesn't happen on eclipse.